# Hibernate join children list with parent entity in one query

Tags: java, hibernate

So I have a `ManyToOne` relation between these two tables:

```
@Entity
public class Parent{
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval=true)
    @OrderBy(clause="id DESC")
    private List<Children> childs= new ArrayList<Children>();
}

@Entity
public class Children{
        @Id 
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        @ManyToOne
        private Parent parent;

}
```

So what I want to do is to get `List<Parent>` that contains it's childrens in one query, I mean I don't want to use the lazy loading, so I want to Join the childrens to the parents in one query and get List of parents.
How can I reach that using hibernate's Criteria or HQL ?
I have used this query but it's not giving me what I want :

```
List<Parent> list = session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Parent p JOIN p.childs c ORDER BY p.id DESC").list();
```

this gives me `List<Parent>` but when I loop through it I get duplicated parent when this parent has more than one children !!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to explicitly use hibernate-criteria(generally used to write custom queries), you can use the standard OOTB methods in GenericRepositoryHibernate.

The point to note is that the parent bean that you create must have the child property of type child(as opposed to string or int). Which you have already done. This kind of mapping is hard binding.

Essentially this is all. If you are facing some issue - provide the log snippet & explain the issue itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't have issue I have a goal to reach, I just asked to know if there is a simple and optimized way to do it.

Comment: Ok, then you have it. It's simple, best of luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Try **JOIN FETCH**:

```
List<Parent> list = session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Parent p JOIN FETCH p.childs c ORDER BY p.id DESC").list();
```

Comment: SELECT **DISTINCT** p FROM Parent p JOIN FETCH p.childs c ORDER BY p.id DESC

And it, work?

Comment: DISTINCT did the job but still hibernate doing the lazy loading each time I call list of childs hibernate fire a sub query to get childrens ...